# Is there a life for Sitecore .Net developers in a long-term perspective?

Tags: jss, xm-cloud, .net

For a long time, `.Net` was a primary technology for `Sitecore CEP/XP`. Usually, Sitecore developers used `WebForms` or `MVC` for building websites on top of `Sitecore XP` and easily extended or changed the behavior of it according to customer needs that was a killer feature and at the same time a pain point during upgrades to the new major version of `Sitecore XP`.

Sitecore did a significant jump during the last 5 years when introduced `Sitecore Headless` (JSS + Asp.Net Core), `XM Cloud`, and acquired a number of products/solutions that allows building applications using mostly `JS` frameworks like `Next.JS` etc.

So, is it still make sense to learn `.Net` for new projects, especially for developers who didn't work with `Sitecore` before, or it is better to use `JS` frameworks to build new web applications in a long-term perspective?